# What do the various spells do?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have a couple spell grimoires, and some of the spells are obvious, or repeated from the original, but Teleport doesn't seem to do anything, and some of the others I have no idea what they do. What do the spells do?

Comment: Just go to the item in your inventory to get a description.

Answer (score 2):

**Acid Rain** creates a batch of droplets which cause harm to enemies, but not you.

**Fireball** creates a single fireball projectile.

**Teleport** does work as expected, but can have slightly different effects on different levels. It will either teleport you to the start, or at least back some way.

**Erase Magic** removes all magical (coloured) objects in play. This includes the sea snake's bubbles, and your own magic.

**Thorn Shield** creates a shield of thorns around you which damage enemies.

**Obsidian Wall** creates a tall wall in front of you that takes time to break through. Useful in combination with health potions.

**Black Demons** creates a wave of black demons that fly left to right across the screen, damaging you as well as all mobs.

**Black Hole** creates a black hole that inflicts massive damage to mobs that come into contact with it.

Comment: Acid Rain also does not damage your allies, like warriors or octopi. And Teleport on the troll bridge might throw you under the bridge and kill you!

Comment: Note: the Black Demons are ALWAYS black, even with inverted colors.